# n by n table generator only printing one row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have managed to create a js mini project that builds a table by whatever (x,y) values are provided, however; my main issue is that say I want 3 table rows I only get one regardless of the value inserted. I am extremely new to the appendChild method, any extra information on how I could have used them differently would be appreciated.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("smit");
var irow = document.getElementById("irow");
var icol = document.getElementById("icol");

// submission

submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  GenerateTable();
})


// functions to create values of r and c
function GenerateTable() {

  for (var i = 0; i < irow.value; i++) {

    var row = document.createElement("tr");



    for (var j = 0; j < icol.value; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      row.appendChild(cell)
    }

    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);

}
```

```css
tr {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<label>Rows</label>
<input type="number" id="irow">
<label>Cols</label>
<input type="number" id="icol">
<input type="submit" id="smit">

<table id="table">

</table>
```

Comment: You said that you only get one row. What HTML do you get, exactly?

Comment: Just one     <tr>    appears with the desired number of     <td>    's inside of it.

Comment: (you should [edit] the question instead of providing clarification in comment. Also you should use Stack Snippets for HTML/CSS/JS)

Comment: You’re creating a new tblBody inside each loop iteration. As a result the tblBody has only one row.

Comment: @Mark_M Put in an answer please.

Comment: @user202729 It’s a typo. Doesn’t need to be an answer.

Comment: Sure thing, Im quite new to this site and I apologise.

Comment: @Mark_M Then... I'm not sure. It's a (trivial) logical error. Although ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code creating the `tbody` element outside of the loop.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("smit");
var irow = document.getElementById("irow");
var icol = document.getElementById("icol");

// submission

submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  GenerateTable();
})


// functions to create values of r and c
function GenerateTable() {

  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody"); // moved out of the outer loop

  for (var i = 0; i < irow.value; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < icol.value; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      row.appendChild(cell)
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);

}
```

```css
tr {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<label>Rows</label>
<input type="number" id="irow">
<label>Cols</label>
<input type="number" id="icol">
<input type="submit" id="smit">

<table id="table">

</table>
```